# Do I really need a unit test project for mstest to discover my unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, mstest

I want to have the following architecture:

```
- Stories (folder)

 - CreateUser (class library)
    Dependencies
    View
    ViewModel
    Repository
    Tests

 -  ShareStatusUpdate (class library)
    Dependencies
    View
    ViewModel
    Repository
    Tests
```

I do not want to create a separate test project for my unit tests.
Instead, I would rather couple my test to my class library as a first-class citizen.

Is it possible to add test classes to a class library and have the ability to execute those tests?

Comment: Why do you think that putting test classes in a different project makes them less than first-class citizens?

Comment: Visually, I feel a disconnect between my unit tests and the stories. As a result, I wanted to experiment with repositioning my unit tests within solution explorer. I have since reverted from including my test in the same dll as the classes that their targeting.

Comment: There is another good reason not to include them in the actual project: you don't want your actual code (project) to (show any) change just because one of your tests was incorrectly implemented. Admittedly the project itself might not change, but given the folder organisation of VS projects, it would still look that way from a source control point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Try modify your .csproj to add this `ProjectTypeGuid` for test projects:    `{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}`.

Comment: How does this help? You need to explain this answer.